# Is there a way to override user_admin_account?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to override the [user_admin_account function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.admin.inc/function/user_admin_account/7) (which list users in backoffice).

Is there a way to do that without modify the core? I don't see any hook to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is a form so you can implement [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module (or even a theme as it's an alter hook).

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_admin_account') {
    $form['something']['#default_value'] = 'something else';
  }
}
```